# export all the content of r script into pdf

Tags: r, pdf, export

I would want to export all the content of r script into pdf. Could it be possible?
I used these commands export, but what I see I just exported graphics

```
pdf(file = "example.pdf")
  dev.off()
```

Thank you!

```
    setwd("C:/Users/Prat/Desktop/c")
    > dir()
    [1] "script.R"
    > knitr::stitch('script.r')
 output file: script.tex
```

In my folder doesn't appears a script.pdf else a script.tex and a folder with the pictures in pdf [image]

Comment: Yeah, the `pdf()` function is a graphics device. The history mechanism is available for saving a record of recent commands. You should make clear exactly what you mean by "export all the content of r script".

Comment: @OriolPrat looking at your screenshot the file 'script.tex' IS a pdf file. Try to open it with a PDF reader and/or change the extension to 'pdf'.

Comment: I did it, but adobe gives me a message of the content is not available.

Comment: Run `tools::texi2pdf('script.tex')` and see if you get a PDF.

Comment: It gives me error Error: running 'texi2dvi' on 'script.tex' failed

Comment: Can you supply the output of `sessionInfo()` once you've loaded knitr with `library(knitr)`?

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with the **knitr** package. Here's a workflow:

1. Save your script as a file (e.g., `myscript.r`)
2. Then run `knitr::stitch('myscript.r')`
3. The resulting PDF will be saved locally as `myscript.pdf`. You can use `browseURL('myscript.pdf')` to view it.

Comment: Thanks, but it save me myscript.tex that it's not pdf format :/

Comment: @OriolPrat Check your working directory. There should be a PDF there, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I've seen, it export me a folder with a pdf for each graph and a .tex folder. But then I still can not export the text portion of the script.

Comment: @OriolPrat Are you sure it's not there? If so, update your question with a minimum reproducible example of your script and the knitr code you tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate html file by using,

```
    knitr::stitch_rhtml('filename.r')
```

As .tex file is not easily readable but html files can view in any browser easily.

Comment: Note that most browsers can then "print to file" - in the printing dialog you can usually select pdf or postscript as output format of the file, as well as it's location. Just try opening any page in a browser (even this one), press `Ctrl+P` and see if you can spot the "print to file" option.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is looking for an easy and fast solution, I would propose using the function capture.output (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/capture.output) from utils.

One only needs to 1.) capture what ever command one wants to run and assign it to a variable and 2.) then print that variable. Images can be printed along the way as you can see. The example on the webpage I linked above does not use markdown.

Here my example with markdown (this is really all one needs):

````
```{r, echo = F}
# fake data-set
x = rnorm(50, mean = 3.3, sd=1)
y = rnorm(50, mean = 3.1, sd=0.9)
z = rnorm(50, mean = 3.2, sd=1.1)
# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

# adding a graphic
plot(df$x, df$y)

# create a model as example
linearMod <- lm(y ~ x + z, data=df) 

# all one needs to capture the output!!:
bla <- capture.output(summary(linearMod))
print(bla)
```
````

Remark: if one also wants to print the command, that is also easy. Just replace "echo = F" with "warning = F" or remove the text altogether if you also wanna have the warnings printed, in case there are any.

[image: this is the pdf file one gets]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but I realized I was working in R 4.1 and ignored the warning that knitr was created using R 4.2. However after updating my R version, I was also just getting a .tex file but when I read the .log file I found the error "sh: pdflatex: command not found."

I used this suggestion with success:

> Have you installed a LaTeX distribution in your system? For rmarkdown,
> tinytex is recommended, you would need to install the R package and
> then the TinyTex distribution.

```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Make sure you not only install the package but also run that second command tinytex::install_tinytex() as I made that mistake also before finally getting the program to create a pdf file.

Here is the link to the site where I found this method.
https://community.rstudio.com/t/knitting-error-pdflatex-command-not-found/139965/3

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below set of codes (you need to modify it according to your dataset/data-frame name).

```
library(gridExtra)
library(datasets)
setwd("D:\\Downloads\\R Work\\")
data("mtcars") # Write your dataframe name that you want to print in pdf
pdf("data_in_pdf.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)
grid.table(mtcars)
dev.off()
```

Thanks.